# Cохранение сторонних файлов вместе с кодом

Tags: golang

Здравствуете, я пишу веб-сервис для служебного пользования, мне нужно standalone бинарник с bootstrap и  jquery.
Я где-то про это слышал, но сейчас не могу найти информацию на эту тему.

Comment: Если вы подробнее распишите, что вам требуется получить в итоге, будет проще ответить на ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, вы имеете в виду [go-bindata](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata):

> This package converts any file into managable Go source code. Useful for embedding binary data into a go program. The file data is optionally gzip compressed before being converted to a raw byte slice.
>
> It comes with a command line tool in the go-bindata sub directory. This tool offers a set of command line options, used to customize the output being generated.

Команда

```
go-bindata data/
```

создаст файл со всеми данными из data. В коде программы данные можно достать функцией `Asset`:

```
data, err := Asset("data/main.js")
```